# Does creating a new passport strategy with every login cause a memory leak?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I have some code like this:

```
passport.use(new SamlStrategy(
    {
        path:'/authorization/saml',
        cert:cert
    },
    function(profile, done){
        var issuer;
        issuer = profile.issuer._ || profile.issuer;
        return Users.findByUsernameQ(profile.nameID.toLowerCase())
        .then(function(user){
            if (!user) return Q.reject({message:'no user found'});
            if (!user.active) return Q.reject({message:'Account is inactive'});
            if (user.isLocked()) return Q.reject({message:'Account is locked'});
            return samlAuthenticateQ(tenantId,issuer)
            .then(function(authenticated){
                if (authenticated){
                    return done(null, user)
                }else{
                    return done(null, false);
                }
            })
        }).catch(function(err){
            if (err.message) return done(null, null, err.message);
                else return done('Internal error', null);
            });
    }
));
```

If I create a `new SamlStrategy` every time like this code does, does it cause a memory leak, or would it be better to assign this `SamlStrategy` object to a variable and just do `passport.use(savedStrategy)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you won't need different parameters for each request I suggest that you create and keep in memory one single object that will be reused many times.

Not that you will create a memory leak, since memory leaks comes from the garbage collector not being able to release allocated memory that is not in use anymore. It looks more like a suboptimal implementation.

> In computer science, a memory leak is a type of resource leak that occurs when a computer program incorrectly manages memory allocations in such a way that memory which is no longer needed is not released. [Memory leak - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)

**By the way;** your code doesn't create many `SamlStrategy` objects. It is instatiating one object on startup and reusing it, therefore extracting its creation to a variable won't make your code any better, its already ok.